# An easy/bitwise way to compute the parity of bits

Tags: algorithm, bit-manipulation

In my case, the parity is defined as:

*the number of adjacent 0,1 permutation to make all 0s to the left, all 1s to the right.*

Note that the permutation of 1,1 and the permutation of 0,0 aren't counted. When the number of permutations is an even number, then the parity is called even, otherwise it is odd.

A few examples:

'101'   odd

'1000'  odd

'10011' even

'10100'  odd

Comment: Do you need more *easy* or *bitwise* way?

Comment: @stgatilov Either, but not the way of the definition.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, notice that minimal number of adjacent 0-1 permutations is number of [inversions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_(discrete_mathematics)): it is number of 0-1 pairs such that 0 stands to the right of 1.

Let (*Ki*) be the sorted sequence of positions of all set bits (i.e. bits equal to 1). Positions count from zero, and from the right (i.e. from low bits). Then there are *Ki - i* zero bits to the right of *i*-th set bit (*i* counts from zero). The total number of inversions is thus *sum(Ki) - sum(i)* over all set bits.

The first part is easy to handle. If *Ki* is even for a bit, discard it. If *Ki* is odd for a bit, it toggles the parity of the sum. So in fact parity of *sum(Ki)* is equal to parity of number of set bits in odd positions. This number can be easily found: mask all even bits out first, then calculate number of set bits (with [popcount](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_weight)).

The second part is also easy to handle. First, calculate number of set bits in your number (with popcount again). Let it be *n*. Now the sum of *k* for *k=0..n-1* is exactly *(n-1)*n/2*. Notice that it is odd if and only if the second bit (counting from one here) in number *n* is set. So as long as you obtain the *n*, you just need to extract its second bit.

Here is the resulting code in C++:

```cpp
uint32_t get_inversions_parity(uint32_t x) {
    uint32_t bitsCnt = popcount(x);
    uint32_t oddCnt = popcount(x & 0xAAAAAAAAU);
    return ((bitsCnt >> 1) ^ oddCnt) & 1;
}
```

As you see, you only need some fast way of doing popcount.